# new to java and I would like my program to repeat multiple times with a new random string for each time it repeats

Tags: java

Only Repeats the same random string 5 times, but I would like it to repeat a new random string on each line 5 times with one execution.

```
// create a string of uppercase and lowercase characters and numbers
String upperAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String lowerAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String numbers = "0123456789";

// combine all strings
String alphaNumeric = upperAlphabet + lowerAlphabet + numbers;

// create random string builder
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// create an object of Random class
Random random = new Random();

// specify length of random string
int length = 10;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

  // generate random index number
  int index = random.nextInt(alphaNumeric.length());

  // get character specified by index
  // from the string
  char randomChar = alphaNumeric.charAt(index);

  // append the character to string builder
  sb.append(randomChar);
}

String randomString = sb.toString();
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
System.out.println("Random String is: " + randomString);
```

}

}
}

Comment: Your first for loop is overwriting the StringBuilder each time it runs. Then you're printing only the last version of the StringBuilder outside that loop, in a second loop. What if you tried printing the StringBuilder in the first loop and get rid of that second loop altogether? You understand that your code can't magically recall what the overwritten StringBuilders were, right? You didn't store them anywhere.

Comment: I would ask you to format your code. In the future there might be others who will have the same issue. Nevertheless, it will help us help you, as well as it shows that you care.

Comment: You are not aware about this site. So, you should visit [here](/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use a method for it? Use a method for the loop and then return it. Then, run that method again and then return it. Try this:

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    
    // create a string of characters and numbers
    static String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static String numbers = "0123456789";

    // combine all strings
    static String alphaNumeric = alphabets + alphabets.toLowerCase() + numbers;

    // create an object of Random class
    static Random random = new Random();

    // specify length of random string
    static int length = 10;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
               System.out.println("Random String is: " + getRandomString());
            }
    }
    
    public static String getRandomString(){
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

             // generate random index number
             int index = random.nextInt(alphaNumeric.length());

             // get character specified by index
             // from the string
             char randomChar = alphaNumeric.charAt(index);

             // append the character to string builder
             sb.append(randomChar);
           }
           return sb.toString();
        }

    
}
```

I also added this code [here](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y2ms9maz) so you can run and test it.

### The result

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but Im getting a few illegal start of expression errors when I run this,

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: @Sambhav.K The code, as posted, does not compile. Take a look at it again.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider check It out now. Does it work now?